# Executing Wake-On-Lan from vanilla Windows cmd?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, wake-on-lan

Is there a way to trigger a wake-on-lan on an enabled computer that's on the same local network using the windows command line without any extra tools? All I found so far requires the installation of an additional program - but WOL just requires a specific package sent to a specific MAC address, so I assume this should be doable using telnet or other tool that's available on vanilla windows?

//edit: I don't understand why this question was closed? I'm specifically NOT looking for an application, but for a way to achieve WOL using vanilla Windows.

Answer (score 3):

If you only wish to use built-in Windows tools, the powershell.one article
[Wake On LAN](https://powershell.one/code/11.html)
contains a PowerShell function that can be used to issue a
Wake-on-LAN package to a MAC address.

The script is duplicated here :

```
function Invoke-WakeOnLan
{
  param
  (
    # one or more MACAddresses
    [Parameter(Mandatory,ValueFromPipeline,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
    # mac address must be a following this regex pattern:
    [ValidatePattern('^([0-9A-F]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-F]{2})$')]
    [string[]]
    $MacAddress 
  )
 
  begin
  {
    # instantiate a UDP client:
    $UDPclient = [System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient]::new()
  }
  process
  {
    foreach($_ in $MacAddress)
    {
      try {
        $currentMacAddress = $_
        
        # get byte array from mac address:
        $mac = $currentMacAddress -split '[:-]' |
          # convert the hex number into byte:
          ForEach-Object {
            [System.Convert]::ToByte($_, 16)
          }
 
        #region compose the "magic packet"
        
        # create a byte array with 102 bytes initialized to 255 each:
        $packet = [byte[]](,0xFF * 102)
        
        # leave the first 6 bytes untouched, and
        # repeat the target mac address bytes in bytes 7 through 102:
        6..101 | Foreach-Object { 
          # $_ is indexing in the byte array,
          # $_ % 6 produces repeating indices between 0 and 5
          # (modulo operator)
          $packet[$_] = $mac[($_ % 6)]
        }
        
        #endregion
        
        # connect to port 400 on broadcast address:
        $UDPclient.Connect(([System.Net.IPAddress]::Broadcast),4000)
        
        # send the magic packet to the broadcast address:
        $null = $UDPclient.Send($packet, $packet.Length)
        Write-Verbose "sent magic packet to $currentMacAddress..."
      }
      catch 
      {
        Write-Warning "Unable to send ${mac}: $_"
      }
    }
  }
  end
  {
    # release the UDF client and free its memory:
    $UDPclient.Close()
    $UDPclient.Dispose()
  }
}
```

It can be used to wake up a computer like this :

```
Invoke-WakeOnLan -MacAddress '24:EE:9A:54:1B:E5'
```

---

The article
[How to send a Wake-on-LAN (WOL) magic packet with PowerShell](https://www.pdq.com/blog/wake-on-lan-wol-magic-packet-powershell/)
has this shorter code:

```
$Mac = "1A:2B:3C:4D:5E:6F"
$MacByteArray = $Mac -split "[:-]" | ForEach-Object { [Byte] "0x$_"}
[Byte[]] $MagicPacket = (,0xFF * 6) + ($MacByteArray  * 16)
$UdpClient = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient
$UdpClient.Connect(([System.Net.IPAddress]::Broadcast),7)
$UdpClient.Send($MagicPacket,$MagicPacket.Length)
$UdpClient.Close()
```

---

And still another PowerShell script can be found in
[Wake.ps1](http://web.archive.org/web/20220707143913/https://gist.github.com/tobiashochguertel/618fdadf327cb1be5465edad8e6acc3b),
to be used as:

```
Wake A0DEF169BE02
```